# Applescript - Keystroke text from variable

Tags: applescript

I have a file that contains some text.  I am able to read this text into a variable.  I want to use the `keystroke` command to send this text to an application.  When the line containing the `keystroke` runs, it produces dialog box that contains an error 'Syntax Error - Can't get keystroke "..content of file.." '

```
on run {input, parameters}
    set inputfile to "/path/to/textfile.txt"
    set fileText to read inputfile
    keystroke fileText
end run
```

How can I send the content of a file as keystrokes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `keystroke` *command* is part of the **Process Suite** of **System Events**, therefore when using the `keystroke` *command*, it must come from **System Events**.

Example:

```
tell application "System Events" to keystroke fileText
```

However, that said, you need to first set focus to where you want it to be typed, e.g.:

```
tell application "TextEdit" to activate
delay 1
```

For example, your *code* would be:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    set inputfile to "/path/to/textfile.txt"
    set fileText to read inputfile
    tell application "TextEdit" to activate
    delay 1
    tell application "System Events" to keystroke fileText
end run
```

Comment: Thanks! I missed the 'system events' part of script.  Still new to this.